# Hypothetically, in the near future, could gas hydrate pingos erupt?

Tags: geology, geophysics, oceanography, glaciology, methane

Could [gas hydrate pingos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_hydrate_pingo) erupt? If so, how quickly? And how much CH<sub>4</sub> could they release?

I'm sorry if the questions sounds silly. I'm new here and I don't know much about gas hydrates and oceanography. I made a few questions earlier this month but I didn't know much about how this site works and I couldn't specify my questions. [Here](https://cage.uit.no/frontpage/news-archive) is where I got the information about the pingos.

I just don't know how quickly (or if) they could erupt. This worries me because I don't know much about the subject and the media being alarmist about it doesn't help.

Comment: Your link is to an index page. Could you specify which of those article(s) you refer to?

Comment: some information about this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_hydrate_pingo

Comment: – Keith McClary https://cage.uit.no/2017/06/01/massive-craters-formed-by-methane-blow-outs-from-the-arctic-sea-floor/ and https://cage.uit.no/2017/06/06/domes-of-frozen-methane-may-be-warning-signs-for-new-blow-outs/ , these articles are a few years old.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, only the owner of the Question or Answer is automatically notified. For others you need to put @UserName , followed by a space.

Comment: In your last link, Pavel Serov says  "And we will probably be able to observe significant changes to these domes during our lifetime.” "He is reluctant to speculate as to how much methane may be released into the ocean should the domes collapse entirely and abruptly. It is not possible to predict when it may happen either."